# Pivot on one column and show the associate value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a `table` with data like this:

```
Fund  |  EffectiveDate | SomeOtherColumns | COST
F123  |  2022-04-25    |  something       | 345
F123  |  2022-04-24    |   fdsdfdff       | 340
F123  |  2022-04-20    |   hi             | 360
F123  |  2022-04-17    |   hello          | 810
F456  |  2022-04-28    |  some other fund | 110
F456  |  2022-04-26    |  some other fund | 220
F456  |  2022-04-25    |  some other fund | 460
F456  |  2022-04-15    |  some other fund | 215
```

Sample definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Fund] [NCHAR](10) NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [DATE] NOT NULL,
    [SomeOtherColumns] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Cost] [INT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

For each fund(F123 and F456 in this case) in my result query I want to have only one row for each fund for each day. I want to take the **top three** latest `EffectiveDate` of each fund, pivot it ALONG with the `COST` value on **that** day. So for example the result will be:

```
Fund  |  EffectiveDate | SomeOtherColumns | COST | COST DAY BEFORE | COST DAY BEFORE THAT |
F123  |  2022-04-25    | something        | 345  | 340             | 360                  |
F456  |  2022-04-28    | some other fund  | 110  | 220             | 460                  |
```

I know I should use a `PIVOT` but I can't even figure out how to solve it.

My query doesn't even compile!

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TOP(3)
 FUND, EffectiveDate, Cost
  FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC
) Results
PIVOT (
  SUM(Cost)
  FOR EffectiveDate
  IN (
   FUND, EffectiveDate, Cost
  )
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's a pivot situation, but a ranking one.

You want for every fund only one line, with the cost for the top date, and the last two before that, right?

If so, you can do it using a CTE to rank the data partitioning by the fund and generate the additional columns for the costs, and then filter it to bring only the first values on the ranking.

Like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Fund] [NCHAR](10) NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [DATE] NOT NULL,
    [SomeOtherColumns] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Cost] [INT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into MyTable(Fund  ,  EffectiveDate , SomeOtherColumns , COST) values
('F123'  ,  '2022-04-25'    ,  'something'       , 345),
('F123'  ,  '2022-04-24'    ,  'fdsdfdff'        , 340),
('F123'  ,  '2022-04-20'    ,  'hi'              , 360),
('F123'  ,  '2022-04-17'    ,  'hello'           , 810),
('F456'  ,  '2022-04-28'    ,  'some other fund' , 110),
('F456'  ,  '2022-04-26'    ,  'some other fund' , 220),
('F456'  ,  '2022-04-25'    ,  'some other fund' , 460),
('F456'  ,  '2022-04-15'    ,  'some other fund' , 215)
```

```sql
;with rankingCte as (
    select *,
    LAG(Cost) over(order by EffectiveDate ASC) [COST DAY BEFORE],
    LAG(Cost,2) over(order by EffectiveDate ASC) [COST DAY BEFORE THAT],
    rank() over(partition by Fund order by EffectiveDate desc) as dateRanking
    from MyTable
)
select Fund, EffectiveDate, SomeOtherColumns, Cost, [COST DAY BEFORE],
[COST DAY BEFORE THAT]
from rankingCte
where dateRanking=1
```

| Fund | EffectiveDate | SomeOtherColumns | Cost | COST DAY BEFORE | COST DAY BEFORE THAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F123 | 2022-04-25 | something | 345 | 340 | 360 |
| F456 | 2022-04-28 | some other fund | 110 | 220 | 460 |

You can see it working on this [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3128966bec3ccf1cc34650a520a2a31b).

Comment: yes maybe not a PIVOT really .. been trying ALL DAY to figure it out. MAYBE a bunch of SELF JOINS would do ?

Comment: There's no need for self joins, you can get the values for the day before and the day before that just using this lag function.
Have you tried this query over you actual data, to see if it also works on it?

Comment: Thanks so much. Yesterday finally used ROW_NUMBER from Window functions. Never thought it gets so advanced to use LEAD and LAG ... I couldn't write it my self with these. Will try now.